# jQuery submit Javascript onSubmit together

Tags: javascript, jquery

What will be the behaviour if I use Javascript onSubmit handler and jQuery submit handler together ?

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="myJavascriptHandler();">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(myJQueryHandler);
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Actually it produces results I can't explain. I would like to know if somebody has ever experienced this.

Comment: well... you may want to at least explain *why you are doing this.  What is it that the form submission or the jQuery submission alone are missing that you'd want to handle it like this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: While it's indeed a bad idea, it would be interesting to see the details of what would be going on in this case. My guess (pretty wild) is that jQuery will add an event handler on top of that inline one. In other words, first `myJavascriptHandler` will be called, than `myJQueryHandler`.

Comment: I would like to make extra checking on forms that already use JS onSubmit handler. It seems that jQuery submit and JS onSubmit works together like a `AND`. I just want to be sure. I can't find any information about this.

Comment: myJavascriptHandler  would be called first and then myJQueryHandler as you can see from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcSHW/

Comment: @Ankur I will accept this if you want to post it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcSHW/) `myJavascriptHandler` would be called first and then `myJQueryHandler`. I think this is because jquery just adds one more event listener to the form leaving the old one intact.